# Get back the webdriver.Locator out of an elementFinder

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

Given I have the *elmFinder* variable:

```
var elmFinder = element(by.css('.thing'));
```

What if i need to get back the webdriver.Locator, a.k.a locator strategy? i.e.

```
elmFinder.??? //=> by.css('.thing')
```

I'm looking after the function `???` if it exists.

**UPDATE:**

This feature has been [merged](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/800#issuecomment-43391346) and we can now do:

```
elmFinder.locator();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This feature has been [merged](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/800#issuecomment-43391346) and we can now do:

```
elmFinder.locator();
```

**Old answer:**
You cannot. The element finder does not keep a reference to the locator:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L103

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i submitted a pull request to add the reference, feel free to +1 there if you agree with the change:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/800

Answer (score 2):

What I typically do is store the selector in it's own var, and then place that string into the selector, so I can use both interchangably:

```
var cssThingSelector = '.thing';
var elem = $(cssThingSelector);
```

Something like that.

**Edit**:

I will also add that you can nest `findElement` calls from selenium webelement objects.

So, if there is another item in the inner html of the `.thing` web element (say, a span tag), you could just nest another `findElement` call:

```
var spanElem = elem.$('span');
```

You can do this as much as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i submitted a pull request to add the reference, feel free to +1 there if you agree with the change:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/800