# isElementPresent and elementFinders

Tags: javascript, protractor

If I define a page object `myPage`:

```
return { 
  myButton: element(by.css('#my-button'))
};
```

And then elsewhere perform an `isElementPresent` check:

```
return browser.driver
        .isElementPresent(myPage.myButton);
```

I get the folowing error:

```
Error: Failed: Invalid locator
```

Why?

I suspect if I remove the `element` invocation, this would work. element returns an `elementFinder` IIUC. But `isElementPresent` is clearly not designed to work with `elementFinder`s. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.isElementPresent()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/cd21f4dc54f4568a3c71f19e5121c79438039a8c/lib/browser.ts#L540) supports *locators or web elements* only, you can call [`.getWebElement()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement) to get the web element from an element finder object:

```
return browser.isElementPresent(myPage.myButton.getWebElement());
```

You can also [get the locator back from an element finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437518/get-back-the-webdriver-locator-out-of-an-elementfinder):

```
return browser.isElementPresent(myPage.myButton.locator());
```

Or, you can use the `isPresent()` method instead:

```
return myPage.myButton.isPresent();
```

Also see:

- [In protractor, browser.isElementPresent vs element.isPresent vs element.isElementPresent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019429/in-protractor-browser-iselementpresent-vs-element-ispresent-vs-element-iselemen)

Comment: Okay, done editing, sorry for multiple versions of the answer.